# How much does an experiment on monkeys cost?

Tags: experimental, animal-models

Including legal fees, the paperwork, the housing, the food etc. (provided there is already a lab with biomedical lab equipment and space for the housing) for let's say the final testing phase of a novel drug over a duration of 3-5 months. what are the monthly and per monkey costs (for the questions sake let us say we have 10)? And how would the costs compare to a similiar study on mice?
I'm just curious because I could not find any figures on the internet.
EDIT: Provided I would get the get legal approvement, 
EDIT2: and it is based in the US.
EDIT3: in California.

Comment: Welcome to biology SE! This particular question has many answers based on the location of your study, Institutional costs, legal costs which differ between countries, Insitutional costs also take into account the fees paid to the technical staff. If you provide your country/location it would help the people here provide a better answer.

Comment: As far as my two cents go. I met a PI at a conference who had to get some brain surgeries done on mice and he said that he was looking at approximately 30K $ per monkey. He worked in the US.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about managing experiments, not science

Comment: @KoustavPal per month?

Comment: @rg255 could you tell me where such a question would be better situated?

Comment: sorry he mentioned it for monkeys. That was the cost he would incur per monkey from housing, feeding until the completion of a single experiment on a single monkey. Nope, now that I remember correctly I think it was more like 5K for the facility and 25K for the surgery

Comment: @rg255 don't you think this question would fall within this site as per the on topic guide http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. I would consider it to be in the third category, "questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory"

Comment: **Questions on interdisciplinary subjects** like bioinformatics are also welcome, **as long as they focus on the *biological part* of the subject**. - I would say financial management of experiments does not focus on biology

Comment: @rg255 playing devil's advocate somewhat, but this isn't interdisciplinary, it's 100% biology. I'd say it falls under "questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory", which doesn't actually require "focus on the biological part of the study" (the way the on-topic page is worded). Personally, I also think it's an interesting and useful question, and I can't think of another SE that would be able to cover it better.

Comment: @rg255 but you should also consider the fact that only an Investigator or a scientist who has written a grant for experimenting on monkeys can provide a reasonable answer to this.

Comment: I would not consider this off-topic but  the cost of the experiment will very much depend on the kind of experiment, the country of residence (local laws and taxes) and the kind of monkey as well. Therefore the question is broad. @daveid you should talk to someone near you for better understanding. BTW, check [this](http://www.cnprc.ucdavis.edu/) out.

Comment: Also there's no attempt to work out the costs for themselves (lack of effort so "homework") and is very broad - the cost will vary greatly with the type of experiment

Comment: @rg255 I would say this is specific enough - I know some scientists who do animal experiments (not on primates and not in the US, otherwise I could attempt an answer) and generally all you need for a grant application costing is the number (and type) of animals, the experiment duration and the containment level (if the work requires it). And to be honest this is an area where there is so little public information it would be difficult for the OP to get any information themselves.

Comment: I contacted http://www.understandinganimalresearch.org.uk/ and they've offered to send me some information about this next week.

Comment: @arboviral +1 above and beyond!

Comment: I attended a seminar yesterday by Prof. Martin Hofmann-Apitius which described literature/data mining to generate the knowledge of a subsystem (+ bel) correlated against the funding invested into that subsystem. You can use this to find which parts of a system are over-funded (and exhaustive) or underfunded and incomplete, and this can potentially guide you to a more efficient answer. Although I see the point of this question, a much more apt question is "How much does a result cost when studying disease/system X?" I now see those questions will be much more answerable in a few years time!